# How to increment local variable inside Razor Syntax, MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on MVC3, i have a situation where i want to do something like this:

```
<Div>
   @Code
       Dim i = 1
   End Code
   ....
   some where, i want to increment i's value, expect 'i' value should be incremented by 1 for subsequent use.
  @i = @i + 1
  ..
</div>
```

but razor is throwing wrong syntax error message. Could someone help me how to do this properly in side razor code.

Thank you,
Rey.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know VB, but in C# u can use

```
@{i = i + 1;}
```

or

```
@{ i++; /* or i += 1; */ }
```

**UPDATE:**
I think in VB must be:

```
@Code
    i = i + 1
End Code
```

test it!

**UPDATE:**
I create a MVC3 app with VB and test this code:

```
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Index"
    Dim i = 0
End Code

<h1>@i</h1>

<h2>Index</h2>

@Code
    i = i + 1
End Code

<h1>@i</h1>
```

It works! post your markup, if u can.

Comment: Its not working, i tred to put this code block inside my razor code and its still says razor invalid syntax. my view contains Razor code and markup. i want to increment i's value after some markup.

Comment: Can u put your markup here? it seems the error is not thrown from this. I create a MVC3 app with VB and test the code, and it works!